# Is there a limit to the number of requests bottle will handle, when running as a Windows service?

Tags: python, windows, bottle

I have a python program that I run as a Windows service (built with py2exe).

My python program imports 'bottle.py' and handles various Restful api requests.

When I fire requests at my service at the rate of one every 50 millseconds, eventually my python program stops responding after about 2000 requests, and after approximately 20 seconds, returns the HTTP response message "read timeout".

I should add here, that on receiving a Restful API request, I simply send a response back. Anything meaningful has been commented out.

When I run the python program as a regular Windows executable (i.e. not a Windows service), I do not see this problem.

Does anyone know if this is to do with bottle? 
How best to debug this?

Below is the file `restapi.py`:

```
import json
import logging
from bottle import route, run
from bottle import get, post, delete
from bottle import request
from bottle import KillableWSGIRefServer

logger = logging.getLogger('RestAPI')

def _create_response(command, status):
    logger.info('_create_response() Enter')
    return '''<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>
<response>
    <command>''' + command + '''</command>
    <statuscode>''' + str(status) + '''</statuscode>
</response>'''

def _create_json_response(command, status):
    logger.info('_create_response() Enter')
    return {"command" : command, "status" : status}

@route('/openapi/hello', method='POST')
def _hello():            
    return _create_response("hello",0)

@route('/openapi/start', method='POST')
def _start():
    logger.info('_start() Enter')
    return _create_response("start",0)

@route('/openapi/multicheckin', method='POST')
def _multicheckin():
    logger.info('_multicheckin() Enter')    
    return _create_response("multicheckin",0)    

@route('/openapi/multicheckout', method='POST')
def _multicheckout():
    logger.info('_multicheckout() Enter')
    return _create_response("multicheckout",0)

def start(host, port):
    logger.info('start() Enter')
    global myServer
    myServer = KillableWSGIRefServer(host=host, port=port)
    run(server=myServer)

def stop():
    logger.info('stop() Enter')
    myServer.stop()
```

The RestAPI `start()` function is called form another module via:

```
restapi.start(self.host, self.port)
```

Comment: You should always try to provide a snippet of code to help users understand what you're doing wrong. It's hard to know how to help if we can't see the problem.

Comment: @Chackle - thanks I've just posted the code.

Comment: try redirecting stdout  when running inside a service : `sys.stdout = file(os.devnull, "w")`

Comment: @Alexander, the application already logs to a file, and I am not printing anything to stdout.